# Convert SVG filter applied image to binary or base64 to save in backend

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg-filters

I am displaying an image in GUI and applied SVG filters to it. Now my requirement is to save this altered image[with SVG filter applied] by converting to binary or base64. I tried converting using canvas. But could not achieve it. Here is what i have tried till now. Can anyone give some tips to proceed with.

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/prhkv0y8/3/)

```
<div class="item active filtered" data-slide-number="0">
    <svg style="overflow: hidden; height: 637px; width: 546px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
        <defs>
            <filter id="svgBlur" width="110%" height="110%">
                <feComponentTransfer id="bFilter">
                    <feFuncR id="brightness1" class="brgt" type="linear" slope="2"></feFuncR>
                    <feFuncG id="brightness2" class="brgt" type="linear" slope="1"></feFuncG>
                    <feFuncB id="brightness3" class="brgt" type="linear" slope="1"></feFuncB>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feComponentTransfer id="cFilter">
                    <feFuncR id="contrast1" class="cnst" type="linear" slope="1" intercept="-0.01"></feFuncR>
                    <feFuncG id="contrast2" class="cnst" type="linear" slope="1" intercept="-0.01"></feFuncG>
                    <feFuncB id="contrast3" class="cnst" type="linear" slope="1" intercept="-0.01"></feFuncB>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feComponentTransfer id="gFilter">
                    <feFuncR id="gamma1" class="gama" type="gamma" amplitude="1" exponent="1" offset="0"></feFuncR>
                    <feFuncG id="gamma2" class="gama" type="gamma" amplitude="1" exponent="1" offset="0"></feFuncG>
                    <feFuncB id="gamma3" class="gama" type="gamma" amplitude="1" exponent="1" offset="0"></feFuncB>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feColorMatrix id="saturation" type="saturate" values="1"></feColorMatrix>
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <g id="viewport-20160404045307934" class="svg-pan-zoom_viewport" transform="matrix(1.011111111111111,0,0,1.011111111111111,2.52222222222224,0)">
            <image xlink:href="https://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/caplio/r7/img/sample_03.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="90%" id="imageStyling" height="630px" style="height: 630px; width: 536px;" filter="url(#svgBlur)" name="ipsDF14-2-29Feb16-9d80-1a94a2e8c121"></image>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

    <button id="save">Save</button>

    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>



$(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = document.querySelector('button');
    var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    $("#save").click(function() {

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
        var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

        var img = new Image();
        var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {
            type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
        });
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
        alert(JSON.stringify(url));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to [security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image#Restrictions) you won't be able to convert SVG to image in many cases, especially if the SVG points to external sources. Some browsers accepts in-lined resources like images and CSS, but even with that done some browsers such as IE will not allow it.

Option 2 is to draw the image to a canvas and use the new ["filter" property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) of the context. Currently it's only Firefox that supports it but only if you enable it through flags (`canvas.filters.enabled`). Other vendors are somewhat lukewarm to the idea so there is limited support. However, if this is a private project then it may be a good enough solution; filters allow you to apply filters directly to the bitmap without going through SVG using the same definitions. If this is a public project you are left with option 3 below -

Option 3 is to implement the filter algorithms in code and apply them to the canvas. It's a bit more work (actually quite a bit more) but hey, we are developers and coding is fun!! :)

You can find the basis and formulas for filters in the [SVG specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html) as well as elsewhere.

Or check some [libraries](http://techslides.com/instagram-image-filters-with-html5-canvas) which already went through the hoops.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed post. Going to choose Option 3. Happy coding :)

Comment: For option 1 I wrote [this script](https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap) which will handle most of accessible external resources and implement it back into the svg before it's drawn to the canvas. Still, IE<Edge restrictions do apply, but for these browsers, a simple right click on the svg + `save as... *.png` is possible. For option 2, webkit browsers did implement some (at least `blur()`, `saturate()`, an `url()`! ) under the `Experimental canvas features` flag too, yeeha realtime GPU accelerated filtering on the canvas is coming! Unfortunately, option 3, is still the only cross-browser one.